# URL Rewriting for sub-folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a URL like this:

```
http://domain.com/subfolder/file.php?src=quick-brown-fox&m=1&size=320x480
```

.. changed to:

```
http://domain.com/subfolder/file/quick-brown-fox/320x480
```

I updated the htaccess with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but I'm getting a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in subfolder/.htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Then capture the URI in php.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this rule in `/subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/

RewriteRule ^(file)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?src=$2&m=1&size=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: I'm already doing `$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; $params = explode("/", $request);` in the `file.php` just need to redirect to that file

Comment: You can avoid `explode` and directly get it using `$_GET` array and yes `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is still available.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. The problem with using query string is that it keeps on changing, so its better if I handle it inside PHP

Comment: Unless you write what doesn't work I can't help you. Start with simple answer to this? What happens when you enter `http://domain.com/subfolder/file/quick-brown-fox/320x480` in browser? Do you get any error or what?

Comment: Nevermind about the query string, I just need to know how all requests to file.php no matter if they're `http://domain.com/subfolder/file/quick-brown-fox/320x480` or just `http://domain.com/subfolder/file`