# URL rewriting for sub-directory without changing base

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the following URL:

```
https://www.example.com/tools/tool.php?id=predict-backlinks
```

To:

```
https://www.example.com/tools/predict-backlink
```

As suggested here: [URL Rewriting for sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215708/url-rewriting-for-sub-folder)

Now the working URL is `https://www.example.com/tools/tool/predict-backlink`

The following code is working fine but `tool` is getting added in the URL. I want it to work without `tool` in the URL.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tools/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^tool/(.*) tool.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: did you try to run this command: a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should do it for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/tools/%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

What this does is grabs your query `id=` and using the RewriteRule will append this onto the end of your URL using `%1`.

The `?` is there to stop the original query from appearing on the end also. The entire rewrite is done using 301 redirection.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for updating question, much clearer now. The reason it is adding `tool/` is because of this part of your RewriteRule prefix `^tool/(.*)`. You're adding it yourself.

Simply remove `tool/` from the RewriteRule and it should work without adding `tool`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) tool.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: you've set `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` yes?